# Can I hard code a value into column in the SELECT clause

Tags: sql

I want to populate column SURVEY_TYPE_ID with 1
Can I do this like so?

```
  SELECT                
         SURVEY_ID,
         SKILL_ID,
         1 AS SURVEY_TYPE_ID, 
 From Table A
```

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: Well, actually, I don`t have the system to write it in, I`m a modeler, that is why I`ve asked.

Answer (score 1):

This should work as it is:

```sql
  SELECT                
         SURVEY_ID,
         SKILL_ID,
         1 AS SURVEY_TYPE_ID
 From Table A
```

Also, if you want to populate string in the column value just add quotes.

```sql
  SELECT                
         SURVEY_ID,
         SKILL_ID,
         'id_123' AS SURVEY_TYPE_ID
 From Table A
```

Comment: Hi, yes I know his question is intended for integer only, just adding a similar piece of information that he may require in future, also thanks for correcting me !!

Comment: Thank you guys (that helped)! And the ones that wondered: If I could have written it myself, I would. There was a reason why I`ve posted it here, and it wasn`t laziness

Answer (score 0):

This query returns a result set with a third column whose value is `1`:

```
SELECT SURVEY_ID, SKILL_ID, 1 AS SURVEY_TYPE_ID 
FROM Table_A
```

(This is the same as your query with the spurious comma removed.)

If you want to change the value of the column in the table, then you need `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE Table_A
    SET SURVEY_TYPE_ID = 1;
```

If you want to add a new column to the table, then the syntax varies depending on the database, but generally something like this:

```
ALTER Table_A ADD COLUMN SURVEY_TYPE_ID INT DEFAULT 1;
```